# Vue.js & Vuex - Store access token in store and redirect user to an URL for login

Tags: javascript, vue.js, timestamp, vuex, mutation

I'm trying to store the access token into the createStore (index.js) and then redirect the user to go to another webpage once they login.

For this I need to create a mutation within mutations.js so that I can set the access token and set the refresh token. The refresh should be like a time stamp.

The test.vue is where the login code is to validate the user.

So, basically I need to create  a function, set the access token, set the refrefresh token and then redirect the user to another webpage once they pressh the login button.

Many thanks in advance!

index.js:

```
import vuex from 'vuex';
import mutations from './mutations';

const createStore = () =>{
    return new vuex.Store({
        state: {
            accessToken: "halo",
            access_token: response.data.access_token,
            refresh: response.data.refresh_token
        },
        getters:{
            accessToken(state, getters){
                return state.accessToken;
            }
        },
        mutations
    });
};

export default createStore;
```

mutations.js:

```
const mutations = {
    setToken(state, token) {
      state.accessToken = token;
    }
  }

  export default mutations;
```

test.vue:

```
<template>
    <form>
        <div class="login">
            <div>
                <input name="email" type="text" v-model="email" v-validate="'required'" placeholder="Email" class="eSection" id="email">
                <p v-show="wrong.email">
                    Email is missing or incorrect. Please try again!
                </p>

                <i name="emailFormat" type="text" v-validate="'required|emailFormat'" placeholder="Email" class="eSection" id="email"></i>
                <p v-show="wrong.emailFormat">
                    Not valid email!
                </p>

                <input name="password" type="password" v-model="password" v-validate="'required'" placeholder="Password" class="pSection"
                    id="password">
                <p v-show="wrong.password">
                    Password is missing or incorrect. Please try again!
                </p>

                <p v-show="wrong.all">
                    Login Details Incorrect!
                </p>

                <button type="button" class="log" @click="login">LogIn</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            email: "test@gmail.com",
            password: "123456",
            flag: false,
            wrong: {
                email: false,
                emailFormat: false,
                password: false,
                all: false
            },
        }
    },

    methods: {
        login: function (index) {

            this.wrong.email = false;
            this.wrong.password = false;
            this.wrong.all = false;
            this.wrong.emailFormat = false;

            axios.post(`https://api.ticket.co/auth/login`, {
                    email: this.email,
                    password: this.password
                })

                .then(response => {
                    // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
                    console.log(response.data)
                    console.log(response.status)
                })

                .catch(e => {
                    console.log(e)
                    console.log(e.response.status)

                    var vueObject = this

                    switch (e.response.status) {
                        case 400:
                            if (!vueObject.email) {
                                console.log(1)
                                this.wrong.email = true;
                            } else if (!vueObject.emailFormat) {
                                console.log(2)
                                this.wrong.emailFormat = true;
                            };

                            if (!vueObject.password) {
                                console.log(3)
                                this.wrong.password = true;
                            }
                            break;

                        case 401:
                            console.log(4)
                            this.wrong.all = true;
                            break;
                    }
                })
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two possible solution for this problem.

- First: you can use [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/). In that case, there will be no
  page refresh, *just component change*. That way untill you refresh
  the page, every vuex state will live. (But its not the best
  solution).
- Second; You can write a rest call, what is give you back the actual
  user token, if the user authenticated. So only this rest api call use
  session authentication and / or CSRF token (check [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) if you
  don't know it). One of the most elegant way if you use **axios
  interceptor** (run before every axios call), what will get the token if
  the user is authenticated. Check this [github comment](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1383#issuecomment-377870814) for futher
  information. (Make sure, that session timeout is longer then token
  lifetime :) )

Comment: Could you please give me some more advise on how I can actually do the coding for this, as I am very stuck. Many thanks for the answer as it has given some better insight and Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are welcome! You should define the axios interceptor, where you create the axios (in bootstrap.js). Be aware, using the same axios inside the axios. it cause infinite loop. I suggest you to use an another axios object inside the main axios, or use the native js ajax call inside the interceptor.

Comment: If you don't making this a bit more clearer to me and I am new to vuejs, vuex and axios. So, I really need the help. Also, I don't have a bootstrap.js. Thanks again!

Comment: If you are that new, I recommend you to watch some tutorial about the vuejs on youtube!

Comment: Ok. But, could you please tell me the basics on how to write the rest call and using the axios interceptor within my code that I am using. Many thanks!

Comment: Its complicated to write here. Thats why I suggest you the youtube.